# appengine_config.py in Google App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine

It seems impossible to find any useful info about it, What does that file do? what are some common usage of that file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is a config file used by parts of Appengine, notably [Appstats](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/appstats.html). You can read more about in by reading some code in the SDK, [this](http://groups.google.com/group/google-appengine-python/browse_thread/thread/59f788fe466417de/0970767831566554) thread has some links to the relevant code.

Star issue [4384](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=4384) if you would like docs about it.

Answer (score 9):

There are docs now:
http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/appengineconfig.html

One of real usages is here in "configuring EngineAuth" section:
https://github.com/scotch/engineauth